# Does server-side http request has the same cross-domain policy?

Tags: javascript, http

I know that the browser-side has the same origin policy, we need to set cors or use jsonp... But if the http request is sent from server-side like nodejs or java, does it has some policy? And what the hostname in the request header? a IP?

Comment: No, CORS is not an issue - which is why I suggested it in your previous question ... `And what the hostname in the request header` huh? just make a request

Comment: CORS will maintained by the web server where the web site is hosted not in your nodejs or java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CORS is browser specific - server to server there will be no CORS issues...